# Exception has occurred: JSONDecodeError App Store Connect Financial API using Python

Tags: python-3.x, app-store-connect

I am trying to get financial data from my APP store connect account and am receiving a JSON error, see below:

```
import requests, time, json
from authlib.jose import jwt

KEY_ID = "KEY"
ISSUER_ID = "ID"
EXPIRATION_TIME = int(round(time.time() + (20.0 * 60.0))) # 20 minutes timestamp
PATH_TO_KEY = "C:\\Users\\justi\\Desktop\\Script Files\\App Store Connect\\private_key\\AuthKey_KEY.p8"
with open(PATH_TO_KEY, 'r') as f:
    PRIVATE_KEY = f.read()

header = {
    "alg": "ES256",
    "kid": KEY_ID,
    "typ": "JWT"
}

payload = {
    "iss": ISSUER_ID,
    "exp": EXPIRATION_TIME,
    "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1"
}

# Create the JWT
token = jwt.encode(header, payload, PRIVATE_KEY)

# URL Query Params
report_type = "filter[reportType]=FINANCE_DETAIL"
region_code = "filter[regionCode]=Z1"
report_date = "filter[reportDate]=2021-03"
vendor_number = "filter[vendorNumber]=VEND_###"

# API Request
JWT = 'Bearer ' + token.decode()
URL = 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/financeReports?'+ report_type +'&' +region_code+ '&' + report_date + '&' +vendor_number
HEAD = {'Authorization': JWT}



r = requests.get(URL, params={'limit': 200}, headers=HEAD)


# Write the response in a pretty printed JSON file
with open('financial_report.json', 'w') as out:
    out.write(json.dumps(r.json(), indent=4))
```

I am getting a 200 response from my r object but when I go to dump the JSON data, here is my error:
https://www.screencast.com/t/ODMojS13WH

Has any one seen this before?

Is the response not a JSON object (which would be strange)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. check if r.ok is True
2. check if  r.json() returns json string. Use print statement.
3. Also r.text may be enough to write json to output file.

Example :

```
r = requests.get(URL, params={'limit': 200}, headers=HEAD)
print(r.json())
print(r.text())
```

Comment: I have found the answer, Apple API returns a compressed file:

'code'
r = requests.get(URL, params={'limit': 200}, headers=HEAD)

decompressed_data=zlib.decompress(r.content, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
data = StringIO(decompressed_data.decode("utf-8"))

print(data.read())
'code'

Answer (score 0):

[Finance Reports Endpoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/download_finance_reports) response content type is `application/a-gzip`, not `application/json`, so as you have commented, you have to decompress the binary content yourself.

However, there is a drawback in your code:

```py
decompressed_data=zlib.decompress(r.content, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

`response.content` triggers [python-requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/) to load the content at once into memory, it could consume large amount of memory for large gzip responses.

Use `response.raw` file-like object and decompress data incrementally is more preferable. You can find [example code here](https://github.com/codinn/applaud/blob/master/applaud/schemas/responses.py#L46).

Or you can use [applaud](https://github.com/codinn/applaud) directly, it is a Python client library for accessing App Store Connect API. Your code can be shortened by using `applaud`:

```py
import os
from applaud.endpoints.finance_reports import FinanceReportsEndpoint
from applaud.connection import Connection

KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXX"
ISSUER_ID = "XXXXXX-XXXXXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXX"
PATH_TO_KEY = os.path.expanduser('path/to/your/key.p8')
VENDOR_NUMBER = '12345678'

with open(PATH_TO_KEY, 'r') as f:
    PRIVATE_KEY = f.read()

# Create the Connection
connection = Connection(ISSUER_ID, KEY_ID, PRIVATE_KEY)

r = connection.finance_reports().filter(
    report_type=FinanceReportsEndpoint.ReportType.FINANCE_DETAIL, # or 'FINANCE_DETAIL'
    region_code='Z1',
    report_date='2021-03',
    vendor_number=VENDOR_NUMBER
).get()

r.save('finance_reports.txt', decompress=True)
```

Full disclosure, I'm original author of [applaud](https://github.com/codinn/applaud).